# WaveWriter and input file format

Tags: android, audio, wav

I found a class on GitHub that supposedly allows me to write a WAV file based on an input file.

```
public class WaveWriter {
    private static final int OUTPUT_STREAM_BUFFER = 16384;

    private File mOutFile;
    private BufferedOutputStream mOutputStream;

    private int mSampleRate;
    private int mChannels;
    private int mSampleBits;

    private int mBytesWritten;

    /**
     * Constructor; initializes WaveWriter
     *
     * @param path output file path
     * @param name output file name
     * @param sampleRate output sample rate
     * @param channels number of channels
     * @param sampleBits number of bits per sample (S8LE, S16LE)
     */
    public WaveWriter(String path, String name, int sampleRate, int channels,
                      int sampleBits) {
        this.mOutFile = new File(path + File.separator + name);

        this.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.mChannels = channels;
        this.mSampleBits = sampleBits;

        this.mBytesWritten = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor; Initializes WaveWriter
     *
     * @param file output file handle
     * @param sampleRate output sample rate
     * @param channels number of channels
     * @param sampleBits number of bits per sample
     */
    public WaveWriter(File file, int sampleRate, int channels, int sampleBits) {
        this.mOutFile = file;

        this.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.mChannels = channels;
        this.mSampleBits = sampleBits;

        this.mBytesWritten = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Create output wav file
     *
     * @return whether file creation succeded
     *
     * @throws IOException if file I/O error occurs allocating header
     */
    public boolean createWaveFile() throws IOException {
        if (mOutFile.exists()) {
            mOutFile.delete();
        }

        if (mOutFile.createNewFile()) {
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(mOutFile);
            mOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, OUTPUT_STREAM_BUFFER);
            //write 44 bytes of space for the header
            mOutputStream.write(new byte[44]);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * write audio data to ooutput file (mono). Does nothing if output
     * file is not mono channel
     *
     * @param src audo data input buffer
     * @param offset offset into src buffer
     * @param length buffer size in number of samples
     *
     * @throws IOException if file I/O error occurs
     */
    public void write(short[] src, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        if (mChannels != 1) return;

        if (offset > length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                String.format("offset %d is greater than length %d", offset, length));

        for (int i = offset; i<length; i++) {
            writeUnsignedShortLE(mOutputStream, src[i]);
            mBytesWritten += 2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * write audio data to output file (stereo). Does nothing if output file is not
     * stereo channel
     *
     * @param left  left channel audio data buffer
     * @param right  right channel audio data buffer
     * @param offset  offset into left/right buffers
     * @param length  buffer size in number of samples
     *
     * @throws IOException if file I/O error occurs
     */
    public void write(short[] left, short[] right, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        if (mChannels != 2) {
            return;
        }
        if (offset > length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("offset %d is greater than length %d", offset, length));
        }
        for (int i = offset; i < length; i++) {
            writeUnsignedShortLE(mOutputStream, left[i]);
            writeUnsignedShortLE(mOutputStream, right[i]);
            mBytesWritten += 4;
        }
    }

    /**
     * close output Wav file and write WAV header. WaveWriter cannot
     * be used anymore after this method has been called
     *
     * @throws IOException if file I/O error occurs writing WAV header
     */
    public void closeWaveFile() throws IOException {
        if (mOutputStream != null) {
            this.mOutputStream.flush();
            this.mOutputStream.close();
        }
        writeWaveHeader();
    }

    private void writeWaveHeader() throws IOException {
        // go back to the beginning of file
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(this.mOutFile, "rw");
        file.seek(0);

        int bytesPerSec = (mSampleBits + 7) / 8;

        file.writeBytes("RIFF"); // WAV chunk header
        file.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(mBytesWritten + 36)); // WAV chunk size
        file.writeBytes("WAVE"); // WAV format

        file.writeBytes("fmt "); // format subchunk header
        file.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // format subchunk size
        file.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // audio format
        file.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) mChannels)); // number of channels
        file.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(mSampleRate)); // sample rate
        file.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(mSampleRate * mChannels * bytesPerSec)); // byte rate
        file.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) (mChannels * bytesPerSec))); // block align
        file.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) mSampleBits)); // bits per sample

        file.writeBytes("data"); // data subchunk header
        file.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(mBytesWritten)); // data subchunk size

        file.close();
        file = null;
    }

    private static void writeUnsignedShortLE(BufferedOutputStream stream, short sample)
            throws IOException {
        // write() already writes the lower order byte of this short
        stream.write(sample);
        stream.write((sample >> 8));
    }
}
```

The class itself it's pretty straightforward, It basically creates a new File based on the file in input and writes the header part on top of it.

So this makes me think that if I give an mp3 as an Input, I'll get the header plus the mp3 data which would result in a corrupted mp3 file maybe? I don't know this is my first approach to audio and I still have to figure out a lot of things.

**My question is, does it need forcefully a PCM file as input or does it work even if I give, let's say an mp3?**

Comment: raw audio is in PCM format is the lingua franca of low level audio code uses ... to answer your question you can just look at the input parameters data structures in of those methods ... to handle mp3 just pre process your mp3 file to decode into PCM then pass the audio buffers in

Comment: Thanks for commenting. No I don't need to handle mp3. I need get the audio from mic (now using MediaRecorder, but open to any other possibility) and pass it into the WaveWriter class to "convert" it into a wav file. What would be my best bet considering that MediaRecorder​ does not have a PCM output format option?

Comment: @ScottStensland have you had any chance to read my comment above?

Comment: I would guess the audio output from MediaRecorder​ is PCM ... I suggest you try to plug them together ... update your question with any error ... unless proven guilty assume innocence ... PCM is used across every audio processing library ... because its the simplest way to programmatically interact with audio

Comment: @ScottStensland MediaRecorder cannot export in PCM at least natively. Have a look here at all the Outputformat options. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html

Comment: Default ... that is PCM ... which is a buffer of ints

Comment: Really? That's great! Thanks a lot, will try this out